# Angular4で画像移動を止める

Tags: css, html5, angular4

Angular4にて画像をX軸上に移動するようにしてみました。

ボタンを押したら、一時停止や、逆に動くようにしてみたいと思うのですが、
どのようにスタイルを切り替えていいのかがわかりません…。
なにかアドバイスをいただけると助かります。

◆CSS

```
.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}     

.sliding {
  background: url('../assets/test.png') repeat-x;
  height: 500px;
  width: 3384px;
  animation: slide 60s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slide{
  0%{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate3d(-1692px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

◆HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="sliding">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngStyleを使用することで実現できるかと思います。

◆HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="sliding" [ngStyle]="testStyle[kind]">
</div>
```

◆ts

```
testStyle[]=[     // 切り替えたい部分のstyleを記載
  {'animation':'none'},
  {'animation':'slide_left 60s linear infinite'},
  {'animation':'slide_right 60s linear infinite'},
  ....
];
...
kind=0; //<button>の(click)等でこの値を変える
```

Comment: ngStyleを使ってみました。期待した結果を得ることができました！勉強になりました。